# SOAP request javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate returns null

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, tomcat, soap

I am trying to get all certificates printed out in a POST. Using Postman I am sending the POSTs with a certificate but I always get that Certificates are Null.

Aplication.properties:

```
server.port:8443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.protocol=ssl
server.ssl.key-store: src/main/resources/ssl-certificate/keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: 123456
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

The main controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/testmocksoap")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class MainController {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainController.class);
    
    @PostMapping(value = "", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE, produces = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
    public String wrapSOAPRequest(@RequestBody String SOAPReq,@RequestHeader MultiValueMap<String, String> headers, HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws SOAPException, IOException, JAXBException, CertificateExpiredException, CertificateNotYetValidException {
        servletRequest.isSecure();
        headers.forEach((key, value) -> {
            logger.info(String.format(
              "Header '%s' = %s", key, value.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("|"))));
        });

        logger.info("SOAP Request: " + SOAPReq);

        X509Certificate[] certs = 
                (X509Certificate[]) servletRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
        
        if (certs != null) {    
            logger.info("Number of certificates found: " + certs.length);
        for (X509Certificate c : certs) {
            logger.info("Certificate: " + c.getBasicConstraints());
            c.checkValidity();
        }
        }
        else if (certs == null) { logger.info("No certificates found."); }
        String isSecure = String.valueOf(servletRequest.isSecure());
        logger.info("Secure? " + isSecure);
        System.out.println("Context Path "  + servletRequest.getContentType());
        HttpServletRequest req = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        
        return SOAPReq;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was within the certificate. It got stopped within the Tomcat server.